# Is it possible to return 2 objects from a function when running catalog_apply?

Tags: lidr

I am normalizing a set of LAS files. In the function after `normalize_height`, I filter out vegetation with heights below 0 using `filter_poi`, and returning this as input to `catalog_apply`. However, I would also like to save vegetation with heights below 0 as a check.

It doesn't appear possible to return 2 objects (veg_ge_0 and veg_lt_0). It is also not possible to use `opt_filter` outside of the function since this seems to work on the input to the function and not on the output.

Is there a more efficient way (like returning 2 objects from the function to use in a second `catalog_apply`) other than creating a new function combined with `catalog_apply` for filtering the negatives?

```
library(lidR)


setwd("D:/Projects2021/p2021_0101_lidR_vs_LasTools/")
dirLASfiles_Raw <- "LasFiles__original/"
dirLASfiles_Norm <- "LasFiles_normalizedWith_lidR_wTIN/"

interpolationMethod <- tin('', extrapolate = knnidw(k = 10, p = 2, rmax = 50))


ctg <- readLAScatalog(dirLASfiles_Raw,
                      progress = TRUE,
                      filter = "-drop_withheld -drop_overlap -drop_z_below -1")


groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function = function(chunk) {
  lasChunk = readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(lasChunk)) return(NULL)
  
  ground <- filter_poi(lasChunk, Classification == 2L | Classification == 9L)
  if (is.empty(ground))
    return(NULL)
  
  vegetation <- filter_poi(lasChunk, Classification == 3L | Classification == 4L | Classification == 5L)
  if (is.empty(vegetation))
    return(NULL)

  lasNorm <- normalize_height(lasChunk, algorithm = interpolationMethod, na.rm = TRUE, use_class = c(2L, 9L))

  #lasNormFltrNegVeg <- filter_poi(lasNorm, ((Classification == 3L | Classification == 4L | Classification ==5L) & (Z < 0)), buffer == 0)
  lasNormFltr <- filter_poi(lasNorm, ((Classification == 3L | Classification == 4L | Classification ==5L) & (Z >= 0 & Z <= 30)) | (Classification == 2L | Classification == 9L), buffer == 0)  #! LASFilter is depracated. use Filter_POi
  return(lasNormFltr) #,lasNormFltrNegVeg)
}

opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 25
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste(dirLASfiles_Norm,"{ORIGINALFILENAME}_normTIN_vegge0PlusGround", sep = "")
mylasCatalogueNorm <- catalog_apply(ctg, groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function)
```

Comment: Everything is possible. I already did something similar. But please add a example of code so I have something to start with to build an example.

Comment: okay thanks, code added...

Comment: It is unclear what you want to output. Please clarify. Do you want to output `lasNormFltr` + `lasNorm` + `ground` + `vegetation` in a single shot ?

Comment: My current output is from lasNormFltr, which is ground (now all 0'd) plus vegetation heights that are greater than 0.  Since some of my vegetation heights come out negative where there are cliffs and sparse ground hits, I would also like a set of vegetation hits that are negative (lasNormFltrNegVeg).

Comment: It is still unclear. I can't see any variable named `lasNormFltrNegVeg`

Comment: it's commented out. just above lasNormFltr.

Comment: Ho yes my bad. I finally understood what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is definitively complex. I had to read my own documentation to achieve it. The LAScatalog processing engine allows to do almost everything but is consequently hard to use. Everything is documented but it is definitively hard to find and put all pieces together. So we will go step by step and this answer will serve as reference.

There are several way to code it. I'm using my own style following [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-catalog-apply-examples.html) but you can do it differently.

#### Reproducible example

First I'm generating data to make a reproducible example.

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Topography.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)
las$Classification[las$Classification == LASUNCLASSIFIED] <- LASLOWVEGETATION
f = tempfile(fileext = ".las")
writeLAS(las, f)
ctg = readLAScatalog(f)

groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function = function(las)
{
  UseMethod("groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function", las)
}
```

#### Modification of your function

I modified your function so it is more readable (imo) and more importantly it works for a `LAS` object and returns 2 outputs in a `list`

```r
groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function.LAS = function(las) 
{
  ground <- las$Classification %in% c(LASGROUND, LASWATER)
  if (!any(ground)) return(NULL)
  
  vegetation <- las$Classification %in% c(LASLOWVEGETATION, LASMEDIUMVEGETATION, LASHIGHVEGETATION)
  if (!any(vegetation)) return(NULL)
  
  interpolationMethod <- tin('', extrapolate = knnidw(k = 10, p = 2, rmax = 50))
  lasNorm <- normalize_height(las, algorithm = interpolationMethod, na.rm = TRUE, use_class = c(2L, 9L))
  
  lasNormFltrNegVeg <- filter_poi(lasNorm, (Classification %in% c(LASLOWVEGETATION, LASMEDIUMVEGETATION, LASHIGHVEGETATION) & (Z < 0)))
  lasNormFltr <- filter_poi(lasNorm, (Classification %in% c(LASLOWVEGETATION, LASMEDIUMVEGETATION, LASHIGHVEGETATION) & (Z >= 0 & Z <= 30)) |  Classification %in% c(LASGROUND, LASWATER))
  output <- list(lasNormFltr, lasNormFltrNegVeg)
  return(output)
}
```

We can try it to check if it works. It returns a `list` with two `LAS` object

```r
out = groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function(las)
```

#### Your function for `LAScluster`

We have a function that works for a `LAS` now we need a version compatible with `catalog_apply()`. In your example you only created the latest but I always split in two parts to make versatile functions that can be easily tested. Here the key is that you must clear the buffer of the two objects.

```r
groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function.LAScluster = function(las)
{
  las = readLAS(las)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  
  out = groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function(las)
  if (is.null(out)) return(NULL)
  
  out[[1]] = filter_poi(out[[1]], buffer == 0L)
  out[[2]] = filter_poi(out[[2]], buffer == 0L)
  
  return(out)
}
```

The example file being tiny we can test it *as is* without redirecting the output into disk files. The output is a `list` with 4 elements. Each element is a `list` of two `LAS` objects

```r
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 250
out = catalog_apply(ctg, groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function)
out
```

#### Redirection in files

This is the trickiest part. The output of each file is a `list` of `LAS` and the catalog engine does not know how to write that in files. First we create a function capable of writing two `LAS` objects using a single path as input

```r
write_two_las = function(two_las, file)
{
  file1 = file2 = tools::file_path_sans_ext(file)
  file1 = paste0(file1, "_NormFltr.las")
  file2 = paste0(file2, "_NormFltrNegVeg.las")
  writeLAS(two_las[[1]], file1)
  writeLAS(two_las[[2]], file2)
}
```

Now we must tell the catalog how to write a `list` because it does not know how to do it. We will create a new driver for this `LAScatalog`. This is documented in `?lidR-LAScatalog-drivers` and in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAScatalog-engine.html#modify-the-drivers)

```r
ctg@output_options$drivers$list = list(
  write = write_two_las,
  object = "two_las",
  path = "file",
  extension = "",
  param = list())
```

We have now a driver that knows how to write `list` of 2 `LAS` so, we can use `opt_output_file()`

```r
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-drop_withheld -drop_overlap -drop_z_below -1"
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0(tempdir(),"/file_{ID}")
out = catalog_sapply(ctg, groundWaterVeg_filterAndNormalization_Function)
out
#> [1] "/tmp/RtmpgBhEaH/file_1" "/tmp/RtmpgBhEaH/file_2" "/tmp/RtmpgBhEaH/file_3" "/tmp/RtmpgBhEaH/file_4"
```

Notice that it returns the name of the files as defined by the engine not the one you actually used by overwriting the path generated by the engine.

#### Final output

```r
ctgNormFltr = readLAScatalog(paste0(out, "_NormFltr.las"))
ctgNormFltrNegVeg = readLAScatalog(paste0(out, "_NormFltrNegVeg.las"))
```

Comment: thank you this is very detailed. I am stuck on creating the final output in the last two lines. For me, 'out' is  a Large LAScatalog and not the list, and I get an error.                               
  > ctgNormFltr = readLAScatalog(paste0(out, "_NormFltr.las"))
Error in as.character.default(new("LAScatalog", chunk_options = list(size = 0,  : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: Maybe use `extension = ""`. I've updated my anwser. Also you can use `catalog_apply()` instead of `catalog_sapply()`

Comment: yes! it all works now. I used catalog_apply().